# What is a lead guitar and a lick in music?

Tags: sentence-meaning

•   As you master easier songs, move on to more complex pieces. "Sweet Home Alabama" by Lynyrd Skynyrd is basically a repetition of D, C, and G in that order, but it sounds much more complex on the record because of the **lead guitar** *licks*.

Comment: [In popular music genres such as rock or jazz music, a lick is "a stock pattern or phrase"[2] consisting of a short series of notes that is used in solos and melodic lines and accompaniment.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lick_(music\)). --  [Lead guitar is a guitar part which plays melody lines, instrumental fill passages, guitar solos, and occasionally, some riffs within a song structure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_guitar)

Answer (score 1):

- A [lick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lick_(music)) is a short phrase or sequence of notes, typically played by
- the [lead guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_guitar), that is the guitar player that responsible for the main melody in the song.

Comment: I'd like to add that licks are usually sequences of notes that are unique or sporadic throughout the song, as opposed to riffs, which are repeated many times.